# Open Graph Image and description not showing on WhatsApp Desktop Browser

Tags: web, browser, whatsapp

My website’s open graph image/ Feature image does not show up when I paste my link on WhatsApp desktop Browser (mobile works fine).

May I know how to check the possible root cause?

I already use below code...

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Og image testing | inspify.com" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="Most popular business directory of SG" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://dummy.app.app/" />
    <meta
      property="og:image"
      itemprop="image"
      content="https://dummy.app/img/ogimage_256.jpg"
    />
    <meta
      property="og:image:secure"
      itemprop="image"
      content="https://dummy.app/img/ogimage_256.jpg"
    />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="@website" />
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="Author" />
    <link itemprop="thumbnailUrl" href="https://dummy.app/img/ogimage_256.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
    <meta
      property="og:description"
      content="https://dummy.app is your online business directory of Country"
    />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="300" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
```

Thank you